# CSS: How can I select all ul tags contained within ol tags

Tags: html, css

My HTML looks like

```
<ol class='enlarge'>
<li>Larger
<ul>
<li>Normal
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ol>
```

Where you see Larger I want the font size to be larger. And where you see Normal, I want the font size to be normal.

I've tried

```
  ol.enlarge {
    font-size: 130%;
  }
  ul.enlarge {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
```

And

```
  ol {
    font-size: 130%;
  }
  ul > ol {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
```

And

```
  ol {
    font-size: 130%;
  }
  ol > ul {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
```

All are setting the font size bigger for everything in my <ol>

Thanks!

-Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol ul` should be sufficient to target elements needed for reduced font-sizes.

```css
ol {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ol ul {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Larger
    <ul>
      <li>Normal</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had another problem with <ul> tags under the <ul> tag that had already been shrunken, but I solved this by just specifying the font size rather than percentages. Again thanks!

Comment: Nice! Happy to help - I'd recommend checking out Ricky's answer as well for a more thorough breakdown, and don't feel conflicted about selecting his answer as the right one if you feel that is necessary after reading it through, he went above and beyond the call of duty there.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). Select any `ul` element within `ol` element.

```css
ol {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ol ul {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Larger
    <ul>
      <li>Normal
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

Why did your attempts failed?

**Case 1:**

You were missing the class `enlarge` in your markup:

```css
ol.enlarge {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ul.enlarge {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol class="enlarge">
  <li>Larger
    <ul class="enlarge">
      <li>Normal
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Case 2:**

There is no ordered list element (ol) as a direct child, that's why the [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) does not work. Notice that an `ol` element cannot be a direct child of an `ul` element according to semantic HTML.

```css
ol {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ul>ol {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Larger
    <ul>
      <ol>Invalid</ol>
      <li>Normal
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Case 3:**

Similar to the case above, there is no `ul` element as a  direct child of an `ol` element. Which again, it is not a valid markup.

```css
ol {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ol>ul {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <ul>Invalid</ul>
  <li>Larger
    <ul>
      <li>Normal
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yea, can't get more thorough and concise than this.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a wonderful answer and addresses problems in my question as stated. I did have the class definition included when I tested that solution. As for Case 2 and Case 3, I had also realized that my uls weren't descending directly from ols and that this was a problem. I just didn't know how to get around this from there. Again, thank you, and sorry for the poor question!

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use `ol > li > ul {...}` instead of `ol > ul {...}`. Anyway, this depends on the markup that you are planning to use. Just keep in mind that `>` means direct child and this is the reason why `ol > ul` didn't work.

```css
ol {
  font-size: 130%;
}

ol > li > ul {
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Larger
    <ul>
      <li>Normal
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I fully understand you, but what about this.

```
OL LI { font-size: 130%; }
UL LI { font-size: 70%; }
```